# Efficiently re-rank integer vector

Tags: r

For an integer vector `x`, I have it ordered into three separate groupings based on where the indices were:

```r
x = c(1L, 4L, 5L, ## group 1
      2L, 6L, 8L, ## group 2
      3L, 7L, 9L) ## group 3

x
## [1] 1 4 5 2 6 8 3 7 9

## original factor
orig_fac = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L)
orig_fac[x]

## [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3

identical(x, order(orig_fac))
## [1] TRUE
```

If I remove a group, I want to re-number the indices to correspond with `rank(new_x, "first")`:

```r
#remove second group
new_x = x[-(4:6)]
new_x 
##[1] 1 4 5 3 7 9

rank(new_x, "first")
## [1] 1 3 4 2 5 6
```

Is there a way to efficiently address this? `rank(..., "first")` seems like overkill. Translating the below to an explicit loop does not seem like it would not scale well to [c](/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) so I am hesitant to move forward with it.

```
fx_simple_rank = function(x, inds) {
  for (i in rev(seq_along(inds))) {
    sub_set = x >= inds[i]
    x[sub_set] = x[sub_set] - 1L
  }
  x
}

inds = -(4:6)

fx_simple_rank(new_x, x[-inds])

all.equal(fx_simple_rank(new_x, x[-inds]),
          rank(new_x, "first"))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: dont fully understanding the ordering. should `identical(rank(new_x, "first"), order(orig_fac[-(4:6)]))` return TRUE?

Comment: @chinsoon12, I do not think so. The ```orig_fac``` has group 2 on inds ```2, 6, 8```. Basically, this is a question of collapsing. If I have a vector of ```1 , 5, 3```, how do I get to ```1, 3, 2```.

Comment: maybe `order(order(new_x))`?

Comment: @chinsoon12, from ```rank``` : ```first = sort.list(sort.list(x))``` maybe I am overly complicating this and should live with the performance of ```order(order(...))``` but I feel like there are simplifications that can be made.

Comment: there should be some code in the `data.table` project that you can use as well. i am always confused around all these ordering, sorting, ranking...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) option that does not scale well. Note, @chinsoon12's suggestion of `order(order(new_x))` is pretty performant. And thus far, subsetting and then ordering the original `x` is generally the fastest until the subset is around 70% of the rows.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector rcpp_rerank2(IntegerVector x, IntegerVector inds) {
  int n = inds.size();
  IntegerVector out = clone(x);
  int j = n;
  int lead_ind = x(x.size() - 1);

  for (int i = x.size(); i-- > 0; ) {
    int tmp = x[i];
    if (lead_ind <= tmp) {
      j = n;
    }
    while (tmp < inds[j - 1] && j > 0) {
      j = j - 1;
    }
    if (j == 0) continue;
    out[i] = tmp - j;
    lead_ind = tmp;
  }
  return(out);
}
```

```r
set.seed(123L)
big_x = sample(10000L, 1E6L, TRUE)
big_x_o = order(big_x)
inds = 1:100
new_big_x_o = big_x_o[-inds]

bench::mark(
  base_rank = rank(new_big_x_o, "first"),
  rcpp_meth = rcpp_rerank2(new_big_x_o, sort(big_x_o[inds])),
  order_order = order(order(new_big_x_o)),
  order_sub = order(big_x[-big_x_o[inds]]),
  dt_frank = data.table::frank(new_big_x_o, ties.method = "first")
)

## inds = 1:100 

###  A tibble: 5 x 13
##   expression      min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>  <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 base_rank     388ms 410.8ms      2.43   34.33MB
## 2 rcpp_meth    13.2ms  13.7ms     69.7     3.82MB
## 3 order_order  57.9ms  59.4ms     16.8     7.63MB
## 4 order_sub    14.5ms  17.8ms     49.4    19.07MB
## 5 dt_frank     54.7ms  61.3ms     16.4    11.45MB

## inds = 1:100000

###  A tibble: 5 x 13
##   expression      min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>  <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 base_rank   326.6ms 331.5ms      3.02    30.9MB
## 2 rcpp_meth   735.2ms 735.2ms      1.36    4.96MB
## 3 order_order  49.2ms  52.4ms     18.9     6.87MB
## 4 order_sub    15.2ms  16.9ms     45.8    18.31MB
## 5 dt_frank     51.6ms  56.3ms     17.9    10.31MB

## inds = 1:900000

###  A tibble: 5 x 13
##   expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
##   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
## 1 base_rank    16.93ms  17.66ms     55.6     3.43MB
## 2 rcpp_meth   759.84ms 759.84ms      1.32   14.12MB
## 3 order_order   3.84ms   3.95ms    249.    781.31KB
## 4 order_sub    14.39ms  14.73ms     67.2    12.21MB
## 5 dt_frank      7.16ms   7.74ms    126.      1.15MB
```